Reached your quota for maximum Fleet Requests for this account
I created an AWS EKS cluster and would like to add a node group (on-demand, t2.micro), but I kept getting this error message:

Issue type: AsgInstanceLaunchFailures
Description: You've reached your
quota for maximum Fleet Requests for this account. Launching EC2
instance failed.

I've checked the quota "Running On-Demand Standard (A, C, D, H, I, M, R, T, Z) instances" is 1,920, and I just used 5 which is significantly less than the limits. Besides, I can create several EC2 instances from the console.
Also found some articles mentioned about "EC2 fleet requests" quota (quota code: L-DC2B2D3D), but it doesn't seem to exist anymore, got the below error message while using the command aws service-quotas get-service-quota --service-code ec2 --quota-code L-DC2B2D3D

An error occurred (NoSuchResourceException) when calling the
GetServiceQuota operation: The request failed because the specified
quota and service do not exist.

So my question is how to solve this issue? Where to increase the quota of "fleet requests"? Or is there any other reason that caused my account to be blocked for creating a node group?

Service Quotas


After a few days of tracking, the quota limits were caused by account-level unauthorized usage/activities and potential security risks detected by the AWS internal service team.
Here is what they said

Recently, we detected an abnormal pattern in your AWS account that
matches unauthorized activity. To protect your account from excessive
charges, we have temporarily limited your ability to use some AWS
services.

Typically, I can do nothing until I fully re-secure my account.
Check the logs in CloudTrail, and delete the unused access keys, security groups, elastic IPs, VPCs, ELBs, etc, then explicitly confirm the using resources are authorized by you (account owner), the support center will reinstate your account and the restrictions will be lifted.
Hope this provides helpful insights or guidance for those facing similar situations, below are the steps I recommend.

Review Service Quotas
Check logs in CloudTrail
Contact AWS Support Center

